# Why is NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider not intended for production use?

Tags: nhibernate, second-level-cache

The [NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#performance-cache) and the book [NHibernate In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1932394923) state that the cache provider `NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider` is not intended for production use. However, I could not find a reason for this. Does anyone know the reason?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because it doesn't support any kind of reasonable caching semantics (first example that comes to mind: timeouts), and it basically grows indefinitely.

It's intended for testing only, as it just provides the simplest possible implementation of a local cache.

Comment: "A cache with a bad policy is another name for a memory leak." http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/02/588350.aspx

Comment: Thanks! The indefinite growth is already enough reason for me to not use it in my application. However, could you please further elaborate the reasonable caching semantics/ timeout issue? And what exactly is meant with testing - "true" testing (unit testing etc.) or just some ad hoc "play around" testing?

Comment: @Marco: the cache must be able to optimize the usage of limited resources (memory) by prioritizing, handling dependencies, expiration... HashtableCache is enough for unit testing (for example, asserting that calling the same repository method twice results in just one DB call). It's also great for playing around because it's predictable.